# Import TensorFlow data from pyspark

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyspark

I want to create a predictive model on several hundred GBs of data. The data needs some not-intensive preprocessing that I can do in pyspark but not in tensorflow. In my situation, it would be much more convenient to directly pass the result of the pre-processing to TF, ideally treating the pyspark data frame as a virtual input file to TF, instead of saving the pre-processed data to disk. However, I haven't the faintest idea how to do that and I couldn't find anywhere on the internet.

---

After some thought, it seems to me that I actually need an iterator (like as defined by `tf.data.Iterator`) over spark's data. However, I found comments online that hint to the fact that the distributed structure of spark makes it very hard, if not impossible. Why so? Imagine that I don't care about the order of the lines, why should it be impossible to iterate over the spark data?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: A little update: The solution proposed by David Parks works very well, but the whole input pipeline was very slow on my machine and was eating most of the training time. Once I decided to preprocess the data and then store the results as a tfrecords I obtained an incredible speed-up, like 100 times faster. (Back then I didn't try to prefetch the input data and I don't know if this is possible. However, it might help with the problem as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` you define a python generator which reads samples out of spark. Although I don't know spark very well, I'm certain you can do a reduce to the server that will be running the tensorflow model. Better yet, if you're distributing your training you can reduce to the set of servers who need some shard of your final dataset.

The [import data programmers guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) covers the `Dataset` input pipeline in more detail. The tensorflow `Dataset` will provide you with an iterator that's accessed directly by the graph so there's no need for `tf.placeholders` or marshaling data outside of the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` code you write.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it seems like my understanding of these things is vastly inferior to yours, so I'm still trying to work out what you exactly meant by all this and how to implement it.

In particular, pyspark dataframes have a `to_local_iterator()` function that might be helpful. I still didn't understand how to use it properly; but imagine for a moment I make it work: could I somehow wrap a generator around an iterator to call `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`?

Comment: Make sure to read the programmers guide to understand the Tensorflow Dataset preprocessing pipeline. What you want to do is wrap `to_local_iterator()` with a Python generator functions. Then you pass that generator to `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`. You will create a tensorflow iterator from the Dataset which will produce tensors that you can use just like a placeholder or any other tensor.

Comment: Thank you, that was really the solution. I encountered some bizarre errors (connection refused that actually meant that not enough memory was allocated to pyspark) but now it seems to work.